# Java - Error when creating Rectangle2D object

Tags: java, rectangles, ellipse, intersect

I am using Shapes to check for collisions in my game. I am using the intersect method for that. But strangely getting an Error when defining on of the shapes. Eclipse is telling me that this is incorrect.

This works:

```
// Collision Shape
protected RectangularShape col;

col = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, ObjectSpriteManager.SIZE, ObjectSpriteManager.SIZE);
```

But this does not:

```
// Collision Shape
protected RectangularShape col;

col = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, ObjectSpriteManager.SIZE, ObjectSpriteManager.SIZE);
```

What confuses me is that both are Subclasses of RectangularShape

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/RectangularShape.html

I am really no expert in Java so I am probably overseeing something with. Maybe some of you could help me :)

/EDIT:
Here is a screenshot of the problem in Eclipse:
[image]

/EDIT_2: I found the error thanks to David ten Hove. I imported the wrong Rectangle2D.

Comment: I have no problem calling         RectangularShape col;
        col = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 2, 2); What error do you have?

Comment: Eclipse is telling me that this is incorrect. It suggests col = new RectangularShape(...) instead. I do not know why O.o

Comment: Are you sure your imports are correct?

Comment: I found the eror. I accidently imported javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D. My bad. Thanks for the observation :)